# Does exposing a user's uid in the url pose a security threat for Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, security, firebase

I've got a small review system built in AngularJS and Firebase and the only way to identify which review is made by which user is via the `uid` of the user. The idea is when you then click on the user's name, you should be taken to the profile of that user.

So I would then create a route looking like `/profile/{{review.author.uid}}` which could translate into `/profile/facebook:123234243` for example.

My question is, does it pose a security threat showing the `uid` in the url like this? Can it be used for any malicious actions against a user's third party account etc?

I've tried looking through their website but I can't find anything on this subject.

**EDIT:** Note that I need a Firebase specific answer, not a generic one about database id:s.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exposing database IDs - security risk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396164/exposing-database-ids-security-risk)

Comment: Try the search box first please

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Thanks for the link but it doesn't answer my question entirely since it's not related to Firebase.

Comment: That answer is highly applicable to Firebase as well. Sequential, numeric IDs are predictable and have [other side effects in distributed data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase). Firebase push IDs are chronological, so still have a factor of predictability, but also [contain 72 bits of randomness](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html), uuids are very strong. Firebase [auth uids are changing to a uuid](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/s9mv4S46Qs0) in the immediate future.