# Best Practice to Avoid website's credential information to be exposed

Tags: security, web, server-side

Just for a simple example, you can imagine the case can be more serious. Let's say, a drop down list for product category of an e-commerce website contain the real value ie. Category ID that defined by the company for their database. How can we achieve a website that contain no private data leak? Any tool or method? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396164/exposing-database-ids-security-risk

Comment: @AlexanderCampos Thanks Alex! This is exactly what I want!

Comment: Nice question, the rule (1) in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396164/exposing-database-ids-security-risk helps.