# Data ids and security

Tags: php, mysql, security

Sorry if that question was already asked but I didn't find any answer on google.
I would like to know if it's dangerous to let users know data ids. For instance, if a user has as primary key in my data table "users" id=34.

Is it bad, to let him know that in the html/js code ?
Is it recommended to hash data ids ? Which method is usually used in php ?

Thanks a lot for your response

Comment: It's not necessarily bad, but depends on your *other* security practices.

Comment: It's not really dangerous... most popular sites I know allow you to search a user by their ID. From my point of view though, you should also let people search a user through their username, as they might not know the ID.

Comment: Unless there's a special "php twist" I've missed, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396164/exposing-database-ids-security-risk . see also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/218306/why-not-expose-a-primary-key , http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139450/is-obscuring-obfuscating-public-facing-database-ids-really-a-best-practice and (for a different point of view) http://johntopley.com/2008/08/19/database-ids-have-no-place-in-uris/ .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. And really sorry for the duplicate. I didn't succeed to google it !

Comment: Don't worry. A duplicate isn't necessarily a bad question. -- For your specific case: It's not a security risk to expose an internal database identifier, given proper precautions (parameterization, authentication if needed). Leaking numeric IDs in place of user names into IRIs is however a poor choice from a stylistic viewpoint.