# exposing of id's in html is safe or not

Tags: php, ajax, sql-injection

I have a simple page where I am retrieving the data ( Categories ) from database mysql and showing it on the page. when the user selects a category I am trying to load relevant sub-categories on the page for the user to select.

mysql tables structure is fairly simple

Category Table

```
id      catname    catstatus
1       fruits        true
2       vegetables    true
```

Sub Category Table

```
subcatid catid subcatname subcatstatus
1         1    Apples          true
2         1    Banana          true
3         1    Grapes          true
4         2    Potatoes        true
```

When I am fetching Categories I am showing them in a ul tag and my ul li tag look like this

```
<a title="fruits" href="#" id="1">fruits</a>
```

and when the user clicks on this link i am fetching records based on the id using ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).on('click', 'ul.icat li a', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $(".selCategory").attr("id","");
            $(".selCategory").html("");
            $(".selCategory").html($(this).text());
            $(".selCategory").attr("id",$(this).attr("id"));
            $("#mobilenumber").focus();

            $('#usrselsubcategory').empty();
            var ID = $(this).attr('id');
            var catName = $(this).attr('title');
            //alert(ID.toString());
              $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajax/get_sub_category.php',
                data:'catid='+ID.toString(),
                success:function(html){
                    //alert("i am here");
                    $('#usrselsubcategory').append(html);

                }
            });


        });
</script>
```

everything works fine but when i go to html inspect element and change the id of the anchor tag from 1 to 2 still i load the same sub categories for the id, my simple question is that is my approach correct and safe or do i need to consider avoiding ajax as i want to have more secured site. its just a simple one page website, please guide me the best approach.

Comment: The security needs to be done on the server (Check if this user is allowed to read/write that specifc data). Having the ids in html is absolutely fine, as you need them anyway.

Comment: This might be worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396164/exposing-database-ids-security-risk

Comment: Just bear in mind it's a publicly manipulable id - is that bad?